# Lock edits to document in docusign

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I'm creating Docusign Envelope using a template in my account. I've set the tabs from my server and now I want to lock any edits to those tabs from Recipient. Basically, the person signing the envelope should not be able to edit anything besides signing the document. Plz guide me how to do this in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DocuSign [Node JS SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client).

See the sample code [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.js#L25).

If the sender only sets SignHere tabs on the document then the recipient should not be able to perform any edits.

If there are other tab types on the document (for ex: textTabs) then set `locked=true` on the tab so that the recipient cannot edit the tab.

See Tabs documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/create/)

Comment: Yes! this is right but it works only if you are uploading a filled PDF from your end. What I'm trying to do is get it filled by docusign using templetes and setting data from my server. And I want to lock any edits except for Signature tabs.

Comment: If you want the tab not to be editable to set  `locked=true` on the tab

Comment: Worked! Thanks a ton!